# Let $\frac{AB}{OB}=\frac{AC}{PO}=2$ and also $AB=AC$ then prove that $\frac{OP}{MO}=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

[image]

> Let $\dfrac{AB}{OB}=\dfrac{AC}{PO}=2$ and also $AB=AC$
>   then prove that $\dfrac{OP}{MO}=\dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$

My Try :

I know that by Thales's theorem we have $\dfrac{AB}{OB}=\dfrac{AC}{PO}=\dfrac{OP}{BC}=2$
and by $AB=AC$ we have $AB=AC=BC=2$ and $BO=PC=AP=AO =OP=1$
Now what ?

Comment: The equation $\dfrac{AB}{OB}=\dfrac{AC}{PO}=\dfrac{1}{2}$ doesn't match with the figure.

Comment: The figure looks like you are trying to make a 5--point star which would have the proportions of $\phi$ but your original equation does not make sense if it relates to the drawing.

Comment: FYI, this is [Odom's construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Phillips_Odom_Jr.) of the Golden Ratio.

Answer (score 1):

Let $AB = s$, $PN = a$, $OP = b$.

Use the power of the point $P$ with respect to the circle:

$$ (a+b)\cdot a = ({s\over 2})^2$$

Note that since $APO$ is equlateral we have $s=2b$. Now write $q= b/a$ and we get$$ q^2-q-1=0\implies q={1\pm \sqrt{5}\over2}$$

Comment: How come you are accepting only few questions. Are they not good?

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{AB}{OB}\geq1$ but you say it is $\frac{1}{2}$.
You applied Thales' theorem incorrectly. $\dfrac{AB}{OB}=\dfrac{AC}{PO}$ does not guarantee that $OP\parallel BC$. I think it will be $\dfrac{AB}{OB}=\dfrac{AC}{PC}$.

I know this is a comment but I do not have the required reputation.

Comment: Your answer will probably get deleted. As you noted yourself, this should be a comment. The OP is probably still thankful for your help. Regarding that you are aware of this, the comment by @amWhy is a little bit out of place.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1129940)

Comment: @klirk, I know how to solve the question. As soon as the OP corrects his question, I will edit my "answer" to include the correct answer. I am surprised as to why so many people are concerned about my answer and no one is concerned about the fact that the question in its current form makes no sense.

Comment: I edited ......

Comment: @Almot1960, still it got problems

Comment: @NilkanthaGhosal your answer appeared in the review queue because you are a new user and therefore your answers get reviewed by default.

Comment: @klirk, I see. Thanks!